# Adding a line break to phone regex

Tags: regex

I have a text field with an expression that validates phone numbers but I would like to add a line break because right now if the field contains multiple phone numbers the page layout gets completely skewed.

Here is the current code. Is there a better way to write this?

```
NOT(
    OR(
        LEN ( Other_Phone_Numbers__c ) = 0,
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}"),
        REGEX(Other_Phone_Numbers__c, "[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10},[0-9]{10}")
    )
)
```

Comment: this "regex" looks very messy. Are you sure you need a so long code? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Without example input and desired matches, most will not wade into that regex to try and figure out what you are trying to do. Please clarify.

Comment: You have very obviously repeating pattern.  Why did you manually create so many permutations?

Comment: Sounds like you are matching a digit (0-9) exactly ten times and up to 24 groups of numbers.  Not sure, but have you considered something like `(\d{10})` which matches 10 digits however many times it appears on a line.  Play with: https://regex101.com/r/YxAIdN/1

Comment: Oh no, that code can be completely scraped for something better if possible. I inherited this and am not sure how I should update as I am not a regex expert in the least! In Salesforce we have a text field where you can enter multiple phone numbers. If our user enters more than 4 or 5 this particular example has 20 phone numbers the page layout becomes really wide and you have to scroll to the right to view the field. I figured maybe adding a line break would help? Not sure how to do that. I will def try the (d/{10}) suggestion.

Comment: Maybe Salesforce can wrap the text.  Then again, being Salesforce you can find a 10 year old idea that hasn't been implemented yet! The joy of Salesforce.  :oD https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrrfAAC

Comment: Perhaps you could make use of a quantifier to repeat the part with the comma followed by the 10 digits between 0 and 23 times.  `[0-9]{10}(?:,[0-9]{10}){0,23}` https://regex101.com/r/nlkVfW/1